# FragmentPagerAdapter initialize all elements at adapterInitialization

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know that FragmentPageAdapter initilizes(and store) picked + left and right fragments. Is there any way to initialize all fragments at the time of adapter initialization?

For those who downwote - please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
will initialize all 3 fragments together.